# Storing user token in Android

Tags: java, android, security, jwt, token

Good day, I am currently building the Login system for an Android App (it connects to a server and retrieves a web token) and I have multiple questions on the matter:

- What is the preferred way for storing such token locally in Android?
- Is there a library that allows me to encrypt it and store it safely on SharedPrefs without needing to store separately the Key and Salt for the encryption?
- Is it safe to send the token from LoginActivity to AnotherActivity inside an Intent Extra?

Apart, an additional question would be if it is safe to send the email/password combination from LoginActivity to LoginViewModel and finally to the DataSource (EndpointInterface, etc) by passing them as parameters to methods of such classes.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. shared prefs are pretty safe, can be accessed only by your app or root user.
2. not sure about library, but u can use some simple ndk methods to encrypt/decrypt data. it will give you some extra points of security
3. Its safe if u use explicit intents

P.s. if your app is a bank client, than you should n't folow this answer

Answer (score 1):

SharedPreferences is best for storing the data locally. When you app have existence in system the data will present and you can easily access throughout the app.

SharedPreferences mPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,PRIVATE_MODE);
        mSharedEditor = mPreferences.edit();
**for save the token**

```
mSharedEditor.putString("FCM_TOKEN",fcmToken);
    mSharedEditor.commit();
```

**to get the token **

```
mPreferences.getString("FCM_TOKEN",null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use account manager for this case.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html

You can even share your account manager across apps as long as they are signed by the same keystore cert.